# CDF of a Multivariate-Gaussian

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian

I am currently trying to solve some exercises in machine-learning/ gaussian distributions.

I have the formula of a multivariate gaussian density function, given mu and covariance matrix. $\mu$ is, in this case, $0$.

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables, the dimension of the density function is $2.$

$$x=(X_1, X_2)$$

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}\sigma^2 & \alpha\sigma^2 \\
\alpha\sigma^2 & \sigma^2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ f(x\mid\mu,\sigma) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{2}|\Sigma|}} \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(x)^t\Sigma^{-1}(x))$$

The first question is to insert the given parameters and calculate joint probability $p(X_1, X_2)$.

Here is my question: Is the formula with mü and cov inserted already $p(X_1, X_2)$, or do I need to double integrate over $X_1, X_2$ to calculate the CDF.

The next question would be to calculate $p(X_1)$ ... do I then need to integrate again over $X_2$?

I tried it with online integration, and the results are really, really big.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There's some structure missing. What is $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$? Are they random variables? Events? What is $P$? Is it a CDF, a PDF?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am currently editing the question.

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera That is also my question, I am not a math student, I study computer science. I hoped that someone with more mathematical knowledge knows exactly the notation and can say: "Yes this question in this type of form, means that you need to calculate the CDF". 

The information above is everything I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to integrate $f$ over $(X_{1},X_{2})$ so you basically have to solve for the double integral.
2. You need to integrate $f$ for $X_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ and you will obtain the marginal distribution for $X_{1}$, which will also be gaussian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any literature to look up the process and get some help? I haven't integrated for 2 years. And online calculators have huge solutions. And I Never found online solutions for this problem, I thought this is a frequently asked question or calculations

Comment: It’s literally imposible to compute the integral analytically, you do it numerically. For probability I like bertsekas

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am calculating for hours straight to get to the solution. I learned much about the gaussian integral and the erfi(u). 

You mean to set an upper and lower bound to the integral? Or to rewrite the exp in a numerical sum?

I need in the end a function in the form of $p(X1,X2)$.